# Outlook mapping fields

Tags: custom-field, outlook

I have a Salesforce trial account.

In the Outlook Configuration section (Administration Setup/Desktop Administration/Outlook Configuration), I created a custom fields mapping between Outlook fields and salesforce fields.

Everything is working as expected, except for the Outlook ManagerName field. When selecting that field, I can only map to a predefined set of Salesforce build-in field (as shown on the Image), but not on a custom field I defined on the Contact object.

[image: SF-Outlook Bindings]

Note: For all other Outlook fields, the list contains all build-in and custom fields defined on the Contact object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Synchronizing Your Contacts and Activities with Connect for Outlook](http://na5.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/outlook_sync.htm), under [Setting Up Associations for Outlook Items](http://na5.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/outlook_sync.htm#AssocContactAccount), the `ManagerName` field is used to create the Salesforce Contact manager relationship.

> You must select the correct manager if the contact's *Manager's Name* field has a value in Outlook.

As such, Salesforce forces you to map it to a field that can be used to create the relationship.

Comment: If I understood well, what you mean is that I have to have a field on the `Contact` object that is a lookup on a `Contact`?

Comment: My understanding is that Salesforce will try and map the value from the Outlook ManagerName field to either a Contact or User field on the target Contact. As such, it will be a relationship to another Contact/User record. Once that relationship has been established you could use a formula field to expose the Manager Name as a custom field on the target Contact.

Comment: I just tested by adding a custom field of type `Contact` on my `Contact` object. Seems to work, it appears now in the list... hum.

Comment: Hi All, One of my client use to sync Events from Outlook to salesforce.com, but he wants a extra field to be mapped in Outlook called "Type" so that on the salesforce.com when the events are synced he will be able to sort them with thier types. So I wanted to know if I create a custom field under outlook list in Events how can I map it with Outlook. Please help. Thanks, Chirag Verma

Comment: Hi @ChiragVerma. Please ask a new question for this so it can be answered independently.

Comment: Already did: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/35194/how-can-we-map-custommapping-fields-in-salesforce-for-outlook-with-microsoft-out. Thanks @DanielBallinger