# How can we map custommapping fields in salesforce for outlook with Microsoft Outlook

Tags: configuration, salesforce-for-outlook

Requirement: I wanted to sync my Calender Events from Microsoft Outlook to Salesforce.com(direction) and I wanted to have an additional field for it i.e. 'Type' of events/meetings but I am unable to map the created CustomMapping field with Microsoft Outlook.

I need help on how to map the Custom field created in Outlook Configuration with Microsoft Outlook.

Thanks !
Chirag